# Jquery Deferred, дождаться завершения setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вообщем почему-то не получается решить задачу, помогите!

Есть 2 функции, нужно что бы завершилась функция с setTimeout и только потом другая.

```
function ret1() {
    alert('1');
}
function ret2() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
    alert('2');
    dfd.resolve();
}, 2000);
return dfd.promise();
}

$.when(ret2()).then(ret1());
```

Что не так делаю и почему, кому не сложно объясните пожалуйста!

Comment: Вызовите выполнение  `ret1()` в конце функции `ret2()` и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум в этой строке вы немедленно вызываете `ret1()`:

```
$.when(ret2()).then(ret1());
```

вероятно вам нужна ссылка на функцию `.then(ret1)` или лямбда `.then(function () { ret1() }`)